# undefined method `zone` for Time:Class after requiring active_support/time_with_zone

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I'm on Ruby 2.2.1 and have active_support 4.2 installed so I want to use

```
Time.zone.parse('2007-02-10 15:30:45')
```

as described here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

But even after requiring `active_support` and `active_support/time_with_zone`, I doesn't seem like `Time.zone` still doesn't work.  Observe:

```
2.2.1 :002 >   require "active_support"
 => true
2.2.1 :003 > Time.zone
NoMethodError: undefined method `zone' for Time:Class
2.2.1 :004 > require "active_support/time_with_zone"
 => true
2.2.1 :005 > Time.zone
NoMethodError: undefined method `zone' for Time:Class
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `zone` class method for the `Time` class is actually in `active_support/core_ext/time/zones`. You can require that class if you really want to use `Time.zone` but a better approach might to require `active_support/all`

**Suggested Solution**

```
require "active_support/all"
```

If you want to check out the source code fort for active_support look at the github [repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support)

Comment: `require "active_support/all"
=> false`

Answer (score 8):

[`active_support/time_with_zone`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb) provides the `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` class, but it doesn't extend the core `Time` class.

You can require [`active_support/time`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/time.rb) instead:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/time'

Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' #=> "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Time.zone.parse('2007-02-10 15:30:45')   #=> Sat, 10 Feb 2007 15:30:45 EST -05:00
```

Comment: For those viewing this question after the fact, I believe this to be a better solution than my accepted answer above. Thanks for posting Stefan.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

instead of

```
require "active_support"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load all active support:

```rb
require "active_support"
require "active_support/core_ext/numeric/time"
```